# Delay while restart of animation

Tags: android

I'm using value animator to animate a image view. I want to add a delay in Animation listener, i.e in "onAnimationRepeat()". How to accomplish this?

Comment: what u tried, u may use Thread.sleep();

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
public class Test {
private int repeatNumber == 0;

public void startAnimation() {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {Log.i("start", "start");}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {Log.i("end", "end");}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                Test.this.repeatNumber++;
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Test.this.startAnimation();
                }, 30000 );
    }

         textView.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to give some delay before animation starts again.

Comment: Maybe you can have a recursive function that runs the animation and instead of repeat, you run once off and start a new one. But you may need an internal counter to count how many animations you have run.